# whonix, TBB doesn't exist?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, whonix, virtualisation

I just used Virtualbox and whonix gateway and workstation and here is what I got when I tried to start tor browser bundle (it doesn't exist):
[image: screenshot of Whonix inside Virtualbox]

when I want to start TBB, it pushed me to make update but then it says TBB doesn't exist. in any case, update or installation was slow, so, I decided to use advtor. I lost 30 minutes just to import whonix and to start it.

Comment: I've used several instances of Whonix 8.1, always through chained VPNs, with at times funky connectivity. And I've never had any problem following the prompt to install TBB. Just do it, and all will be well! I'm not a maintainer of Whonix, so I can be more blunt ;)

Comment: Upon reflection, I can see how OP became confused. Maybe the "torbrowser Update Check" in Whonix needs to be more explicit. It could summarize what adrelanos explains in his answer. I apologize for being snappish.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. Newer Whonix versions do not come with Tor Browser installed by default. By the time one install Whonix, the default installed version would be most likely outdated, so downloading the most recent one is advised. Also for [legal/trademark reasons](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10888), it's safer not installing Tor Browser by default and letting the user download it.

> decided to use advtor

I recommend against [AdvOR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/), the "Advanced" Onion Router. Reasons:

- No interest from the research community.
- No source control, i.e. git.
- Licensing issues (See Nick Mathewson's (Tor's Chief Architect) analysis below.)
- Absence in the Tor community.
- No Linux support.
- [The Nick Mathewson's (Tor's Chief Architect) analysis and recommends against.](http://archives.seul.org/or/talk/Oct-2010/msg00026.html)

If you don't like Whonix, it'd rather advice to look into Tor Browser Bundle or Tails.

Full disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.